# Count the prime numbers from 2 to 100 with simpler code than this

Tags: javascript, primes

It has to be with just functions, variables, loops, etc (Basic stuff). I'm having trouble coming up with the code from scratch from what I've I learned so far(Should be able to do it).  Makes me really mad :/. **If you could give me step by step to make sure I understand I'd really really appreciated.** Thanks a bunch in advanced.

How could I get the same result with a simpler code than this one:

```
var primes=4; 
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 100; counter = counter + 1)
{
    var isPrime = 0;
    if(isPrime === 0){ 
        if(counter === 2){console.log(counter);} 
        else if(counter === 3){console.log(counter);} 
        else if(counter === 5){console.log(counter);} 
        else if(counter === 7){console.log(counter);} 
        else if(counter % 2 === 0){isPrime=0;} 
        else if(counter % 3 === 0){isPrime=0;} 
        else if(counter % 5 === 0){isPrime=0;} 
        else if(counter % 7 === 0){isPrime=0;}
        else {
            console.log(counter);
            primes = primes + 1;
        }
    }
}
console.log("Counted: "+primes+" primes");
```

Comment: Related: [the Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: I'd first start with trying to understand that code. It's pretty simple. You might be confusing simple for shorter.

Comment: i dont know why "if (isPrime==0)" is right after assigning "isPrime=0". that 'if' is useless

Comment: @sachleen yes really sorry I was trying to say shorter..

Comment: @icktoofay damn that looks like a good reading. Bookmarking it for later. I hope I don't suck for algorithms :/

Comment: some simple optimizations: start counting at 3, increment count by 2, and stop checking factors larger than the sqrt of the number you're testing. 0/1/2 are trivial primes. there are no even primes other than 2, and you cannot have a prime number with a factor larger than than the number's square root.

Comment: @RufioLJ, the code you posted unrolls an inner loop to increase speed.  It is a common tactic to make code perform better.  Prime calculators are known to be extremely CPU intensive.  The answer you accepted is poorly written and would take an extremely long time to find primes if you fed it a high bound of primes to find such as 1,000,000 (hint: the inner loop would execute 1 trillion times as currently written).  I added a comment how he could improve so 1,000,000 primes would take only 1 billion iterations, but that's still a lot.

Comment: I feel like adding the "Homework" tag to this :)

Comment: @Aran Mullholland not really I'm learning by my own. This is taken from code academy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds all prime numbers between 2 and 100:

```
var primes=0; 
var isprime = true;
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 100; counter = counter + 1)
{
    // For now, we believe that it is a prime
    isprime = true;
    var limit = Math.round(Math.sqrt(counter)); // See comment from @AresAvatar, below
    // We try to find a number between 2 and limit that gives us a reminder of 0
    for (var mod = 2; mod <= limit; mod++) {
        // If we find one, we know it's not a prime
        if (counter%mod == 0) {
            isprime = false;
            break; // Break out of the inner for loop
        }
    }

    if (isprime) {
        console.log(counter, limit);
        primes = primes + 1;
    }
}
console.log("Counted: "+primes+" primes");
```

Comment: I was looking for this.. Thanks a bunch I'm going to try to understand it now.. why do you need to set isprime to true? (I know is in the code I posted I didn't get it either)

Comment: Assume it's prime, then do tests to see if it is not.

Comment: I'd say this code would be a whole lot more inefficient than the original

Comment: Yeah this user understood exactly what I wanted! This is all I've learned so far. What is the break; for? Also why is he comparing the "mod" with the "counter"?

Comment: to make sure it is not divisible by any number less than it

Comment: @RufioLJ as soon as i find a number it is dividable by, i don't have to check more numbers. I then know its not a prime.

Comment: @MiniGod, your inner loop should be mod = 2 to the square root of counter rounded up to the next whole number.  Any pair of 2 factors that divide into it has to have at least one number at or below the square root.  This makes for dramatically less overall iterations!  100x100 == 10000, 100x10 = only 1000.  If you were doing primes up to 10000 it'd be 100000000 iterations vs only 1000000.  A lot quicker.

Comment: Also I have another question. When counter is looping by +one for example when counter is 3 what is the value of mod?

Answer (score 7):

I'm feeling naughty today so:

```
function printPrimesBetweenTwoAndOneHundredSimply(){

   var primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97],
   i,
   arrayLength = primes.length;

   for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
     console.log(primes[i]);
   }

   console.log("Counted: " + arrayLength + " primes");
}
```

Comment: Horrible answer but gave me a chuckle... +1

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but your answer gives the primes of values <100, not the first 100 prime numbers.  ;-)

Comment: @Mike Yes but if you look at the code above that is what it does too.

Comment: ...Simplest answer here thoough!

Answer (score 4):

First, you really don't need to use `===` for this. The standard `==` will suffice. Second, you can make all of those lines that are the same thing, except for a single digit into one line:

```
var primes=4; 
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 100; counter = counter + 1)
{
    var isPrime = 0;
    if(isPrime == 0){ 
        if(counter == 2 || counter == 3 ||counter == 5 || counter == 7)console.log(counter);
        else if(counter % 2 == 0 || counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0 || counter % 7 == 0)isPrime=0; 
        else {
            console.log(counter);
            primes = primes + 1;
        }
    }
}
console.log("Counted: "+primes+" primes");
```

You'll also notice that the `{}` was removed on a few lines. This is because a single line of code following an `if` (among others) is always considered nested.

Next, we can change your `primes = primes + 1;` to this: `primes++;` which just tells `primes` to increment itself by one. The same can be done for your counter. We also know that `isPrime` equals "0" because you set it to that a second ago, so we no longer need that `if` statement:

```
var primes=4; 
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 100; counter++)
{
    var isPrime = 0;
    if(counter == 2 || counter == 3 ||counter == 5 || counter == 7)console.log(counter);
    else if(counter % 2 == 0 || counter % 3 == 0 || counter % 5 == 0 || counter % 7 == 0)isPrime=0; 
    else {
        console.log(counter);
        primes++;
    }
}
console.log("Counted: "+primes+" primes");
```

Next, we can do a negative check (`!=` instead of `==`) on the values and combine your `else if` with your `else`. Since we're doing a negative check (for this case) we have to switch the `OR`s (`||`) to `AND`s (`&&`):

```
var primes=4; 
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 100; counter++)
{
    if(counter == 2 || counter == 3 ||counter == 5 || counter == 7)console.log(counter);
    else if(counter % 2 != 0 && counter % 3 != 0 && counter % 5 != 0 && counter % 7 != 0) {
        console.log(counter);
        primes++;
    }
}
console.log("Counted: "+primes+" primes");
```

There are many other ways to write it, but I felt it more beneficial to you to use what you started with and shorten it from there.

Comment: This is a really good answer! Thanks a bunch for guiding me step by step. I wish I could select two best answers.

Comment: You're right that `==` will work, but there's nothing wrong with `===` and it's often a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Of course "simpler" is not defined. :-)

The following can be made much shorter, but has a bit of robustness built in.

```
// Get primes from 0 to n. 
// n must be < 2^53
function primeSieve(n) {

  n = Number(n);
  if (n > Math.pow(2, 53) || isNaN(n) || n < 1) {
    return;
  }

  var primes = [];
  var notPrimes = {};
  var num;

  for (var i=2; i<n; i++) {
    for (var j=2; j<n/2; j++) {
      num = i*j;
      notPrimes[num] = num;
    }
    if (!(i in notPrimes)) {
      primes.push(i);
    }
  }
  return primes
}
```

So if you want less code:

```
// Get primes from 0 to n. 
// n must be < 2^53
function primeSieve2(n) {
  var primes = [], notPrimes = {};
  for (var i=2; i<n; i++) { 
    for (var j=2; j<n/2; j++)
      notPrimes[i*j] = i*j;
    i in notPrimes? 0 : primes.push(i);
  }
  return primes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple (I mean, short):

```
console.log(2); console.log(3);
var m5=25, m7=49, i=5, d=2, c=2;
for( ; i<100; i+=d, d=6-d )
{
    if( i!=m5 && i!=m7) { console.log(i); c+=1; }
    if( m5 <= i ) m5+=10;
    if( m7 <= i ) m7+=14;
}
c
```

It is an "unrolled" [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) with [2-3-wheel factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).

On the one hand, we enumerate all the numbers below 100 (and bigger than 3) that are coprime with 2 and 3, as partial sums of 5+2+4+2+4+... , so that there are no multiples of 2 and 3 among thus enumerated numbers.

On the other hand, we discard from among them all the multiples of 5 and 7, by enumerating them as partial sums of 25+10+10+10+... and 49+14+14+14+... . Multiples of 2 and 3 are not there in the first place, and the first multiple of 11 that needs to be discarded by the sieve of Eratosthenes is 121.

Answer (score -3):

This will be simpler for your Question....

```
 for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
int j = 0;
for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
    if ((i % j) == 0)break;
        if (i == j)
        System.out.print("  " + i);}
```

Comment: -1 Poorly formatted code. Even though it's not required, it's good practice to have braces anyway. Question is tagged javascript, not java.